# Add to auth_user

Tags: django, database

I have this program that gets most of its data from the auth_user table one the django database. I don’t know how to add a new column to it and make it actually work since it doesn’t recognize it when I do. Does anybody know how you would add a column that can be used in auth_user table in the default django database.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a part that well documented on Django's documentation site. I guess you are trying to create [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). But I recommend you to [extend user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). Extending default user model will provide you more flexibility. I hope these two links will enough. If not, please comment me about missing parts to cover.

Answer (score 0):

You can override default user model or extend user model with OneToOneField relation to satisfy this requirement.

**1. I'll show you how to do custom User Model.**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from core.util.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator
from .manager import UserManager

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Username, Email and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_(
            '150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
        null=True,
        default=None
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address'),
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that email address already exists."),
        },
    )

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        permissions = (
            ('user_permission', "User Permission"),
            ('admin_permission', "Admin Permission"),
        )
```

This is like a copy of what they have in their User model. here, You can add new fields.

Make sure to register this in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userapp.User'
```

you can access extra_fields like

```
user.extra_field
```

**2. I'll show you how to extend using OneToOneField.**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    # Extra fields Here
```

then you can access the extra fields as

```
user.profile.extra_field
```

Comment: And I can add extra fields like max_char in it to